# removeEventListener not working

Tags: javascript

**Adds listener**

```
for ( i = 0; i < kbButtons.length; i++ ) {
        kbButtons[i].addEventListener("click", function() { clickKbButton( this ); }, false);
    }
```

**Should remove listener**

```
function clickKbButton ( elem ) { 
    elem.removeEventListener("click", function() { clickKbButton( this ); }, false);
    elem.id = "invis"
    }
```

Everything is working fine, no errors in console, button click works but it's not being removed after I click it

Comment: Why do you change the ID of the element after you remove it?

Comment: @trysis just visual to make the text disappear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.removeEventListener), my guess is that event handler should reference the same function:

```
for ( i = 0; i < kbButtons.length; i++ ) {
    kbButtons[i].addEventListener("click", clickKbButton, false);
}
function clickKbButton ( ev ) { 
    this.removeEventListener("click", clickKbButton, false);
    this.id = "invis"
}
```

[**Simple fiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/XsaXS/)

Comment: You're right. `removeEventListener` must be passed a reference to the function that was added, not a copy.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you should use a variable reference to the `function() { clickKbButton(this); }`, the two functions in your `addEventListener` & `removeEventListener` are actually two different functions.

```
var handler = function() { clickKbButton(this) };
```

then use this handler variable when you add & remove listener.